# Which approach is best at generating random numbers?

Tags: c++

What kind of approach is the best at generating a random 2-digit number (using only the standard C++ library)? These 2 seem like the most obvious, but I want to know which one is better and if there is a better one.

```
//1
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
     std::srand(std::time(NULL));
     std::cout << "Random value: " << std::rand() % 100;
     return 0;
}

//2
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
int main()
{
     std::random_device rnd;
     std::cout << "Random value: " << rnd() % 100;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `uniform_int_distribution` is the best: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution. Your current solutions don't actually produce uniformly random number.

Comment: It depends on what kind of distribution you want to have for these generated 2-digit numbers, like uniformly distributed, normally distributed, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of those is very good. You want a less predictable seed (which `srand`/`rand` can't do), and a uniform distribution (which `% 100` of just about anything won't do).

Instead, use the C++11 standard `<random>` PRNG suite (adapted from [cppreference example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Example)):

```
int main()
{
    // Seed with a real random value, if available
    std::random_device r;

    // Seed the default ending from good random
    std::default_random_engine eng(r());

    // Define a proper distribution that won't exhibit bias
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 99);

    std::cout << "Random value: " << dist(eng) << std::endl;
}
```

Technically, the standard is a bit weak on `std::random_device` and allows it to be non-cryptographically random, but on all major OSes it should be decent. You're welcome to xor `r()` with `time(NULL)` if you want to ensure it's at least non-repeating, though it won't guarantee good randomness.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is it better to use `random_device` to generate the seed rather than the number itself?

Comment: @DarkAtom: If you're only generating one or two numbers, go ahead and use `random_device` directly (`dist(r)` will do the trick in the above code, removing the need for `eng`), but if you need more, faster, seeding a PRNG and using that is much faster. Note that seeding it properly is [somewhat tricky, so read up on making `seed_seq`s for seeding if you need really good seeding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47562404/364696).

Comment: _You're welcome to xor r() with time(NULL)_ - unless first invocation of `r()` returns `time(NULL)`

Comment: @Roman: True. I suppose addition would be somewhat safer if you're worried about bad `random_device`, in that worst case is `time(NULL) * 2` rather than `0`. Downside is that I believe it introduces predictable patterns into good random values (due to the carry), where xor of a good value and a bad one remains good. Still can't believe the standard allowed `std::random_device` to be implemented so poorly without even a diagnostic output to warn you.