# Rand() command generates the same numbers every time

Tags: c++

I'm using rand() in a loop to generate random numbers every time till the loop is complete, but it always gives the same number, what am I doing wrong?

```
 bool PlayGame(int Difficulty, bool bComplete)
{

    
    int CodeA =rand() % Difficulty + Difficulty;
    int CodeB =rand() % Difficulty + Difficulty;
    int CodeC =rand() % Difficulty + Difficulty;
```

Comment: You need to seed the random number generator 1 time at start of `int main()`

Comment: you need to seed the random generator : Also see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69056209/c-random-number-same-sequence-every-time/69056326?noredirect=1#comment122052380_69056326.
For C++ consider using functions from the <random> header file (rand is less random and more "c" then "c++")

Comment: Just curious: there's been a flurry of questions similar to this in the past few days. Is there a course somewhere that's prompting people to write code that uses random numbers?

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes random numbers and c-style arrays ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I'm really new haha

Answer (score 2):

You can use current time as seed for random generator by setting `srand(time(0));` at start

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
 
// Driver program
int main(void)
{
    // This program will create different sequence of
    // random numbers on every program run
 
    // Use current time as seed for random generator
    srand(time(0));
 
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %d ", rand());
 
    return 0;
}


Output 1:
453 1432 325 89

Output 2:
8976 21234 45 8975

Output n:
563 9873 12321 24132
```

[Ref.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rand-and-srand-in-ccpp/)

Answer (score 2):

If random numbers are generated with `rand()` without first calling `srand()`, your program will create the same sequence of numbers each time it runs.

The `srand()` function sets the starting point for producing a series of pseudo-random integers. If `srand()` is not called, the rand() seed is set as if `srand(1)`

so, set `srand(time(0));` at start of the program

Comment: And, in case it isn't clear, generating the same sequence every time is a good thing. It's important for debugging, and, more generally, for understanding what your program is doing. Once it's working right, add a seed so that you get varied behavior.